# Self-referential graph connections between chunked collections not behaving as expected

Tags: rust

I need some help with a Rust function that isn't behaving the way I expect it to, I'm hoping someone can spot my mistake and trash me for it.

I have a struct that follows this format:

```
struct MyStruct {
    targets: Vec<MyTarget>,
}
```

And is wrapped as one of two types:

```
type MyNode = Arc<Mutex<MyStruct>>;
type MyTarget = Weak<Mutex<MyStruct>>;
```

And another struct:

```
struct MyCollection(Vec<MyNode>);
```

And three functions:

`get_parent()` method to select a MyNode from a MyCollection to push the MyTarget to

`get_target()` method to select a MyNode from a MyCollection and downgrade it to create a MyTarget

`connect()` which takes a parent MyNode and target Weak pointer and performs the connection

This is an oversimplification so sorry if it's confusing or I'm leaving something out here, but this works as expected when connecting a parent/target pair within the same MyCollection so I'm confident that these functions are not the problem.

The functions that are giving me trouble look something like:

```
impl MyCollection {
    fn chunk_mycollection(&self, chunk_size: usize) -> Vec<MyCollection> {
        self.0.chunks(chunk_size)
              .map(|c: &[MyNode]| MyCollection(c.to_vec()))
              .collect()
    }

    fn connect_mycollections_by_chunk(c1: &MyCollection, c2: &MyCollection, chunk_size: usize) {
        // Chunked collection 1
        let l1: Vec<MyCollection> = c1.chunk_mycollection(chunk_size);
        // Chunked collection 2
        let l2: Vec<MyCollection> = c2.chunk_mycollection(chunk_size);
    
        // From each chunk in l1,
        for (c, chunk) in l1.iter().enumerate() {
            // If it isn't the last chunk
            if c < l1.len() - 1 {
                // Get a parent node
                let parent: MyNode = chunk.get_parent();
                // I want the target to be selected from the "next" chunk in l2
                let other_chunk: &MyCollection = &l2[c + 1];
                let target: MyTarget = other_chunk.get_target();
                // Push the MyTarget to the MyNode parent
                connect(parent, target);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely, it forms a connection between a parent in `c1` and a target in `c2` but instead of choosing a target from the next chunk, `get_target()` chooses a target that is one index value greater than the parent in `c1`, from the original `c2`, ignoring the new `MyCollection` chunk I called it on.

IOW instead of connecting `c1[0]` to `c2[chunk_size]`, and only one connection per chunk, it connects `c1[0]` to `c2[1]`, `c1[1]` to `c2[2]`, and so on, as if `c1` and `c2` were never made into a `Vec<MyCollection>`.

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like I'm critically misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chunk size was being limited to 1 by an upstream variable :) The code works fine